# WP Customizer - Prevent live preview

Tags: theme-customizer, api

How do I prevent a widget being updated in the customizer preview if a widget field fails a JS validation check? More generally, is there any actual documentation for the customizer JS API? (I mean real, proper api documentation rather than the few examples or sketchy descriptions)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. My widget has a checkbox field, every time this field is checked and unchecked the whole customizer preview reloads. Instead I want to use the js hooks like partial-content-rendered.

Answer (score 2):

Visit this link and read about `transporter` argument: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API

Is that what you are looking for?

Here is an example for you:

```
<?php

add_action( 'customize_register', 'my_customizer' );
function my_customizer($wp_customize){
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'my_section', 
        array(
            'title' => __( 'My Custom Section', 'mytheme' ), //Visible title of section
            'capability' => 'edit_theme_options', //Capability needed to tweak
        )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'my_setting', 
        array(
            'default' => 'option1', //Default setting/value to save
            'type' => 'theme_mod', //Is this an 'option' or a 'theme_mod'?
            'capability' => 'edit_theme_options', //Optional. Special permissions for accessing this setting.
            'transport' => 'postMessage', //What triggers a refresh of the setting? 'refresh' or 'postMessage' (instant)?
        ) 
    );
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        'my_control', 
        array(
            'label'    => __( 'My Custom Control', 'mytheme' ),
            'section'  => 'my_section',
            'settings' => 'my_setting',
            'type'     => 'radio',
            'choices'  => array(
                'option1'  => 'Option 1',
                'option2' => 'Option 2',
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to implement this please? The link is a great reference.

Comment: Sure! Create a file **customizer.php** and put this code in: https://repl.it/EJES/2

Comment: Thanks :D ! The rule of thumb for answers is that all the relevant information for the answer should be in the content itself and not in external links - those are additional references. That sounds like what he's referring to - there's an [`edit` link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/244329/edit) underneath your answer to add in all the relevant information. There's also some [documentation on code formatting](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) ( usually just highlight and click the code button ). +1